# Exit the closure function when the if condition returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a child function alertMSGS so the alertMSGS function checks the values in four variables and gives a alert message that they are not equal, so it will return false to the parent function which is DoSave() its a closure function , from my knowledge (Begginer to Javascript). So if the return is false i need to exit the save otherwise need to perform the save. !! See below . 
Many Thanks in advance

```
function alertMSGS(){
      var currentWeekEarning = parseFloat( $("#_fid_19").val() );
      var totalYearEarning= parseFloat( $("label[for=_fid_39]").next("div").text().replace('$', '').replace(',', '') );
      var currentLoss = parseFloat($("#_fid_20").val());
      var totalYearLoss= parseFloat($("label[for=_fid_38]").next("div").text().replace('$', '').replace(',', '') )
      if( (currentWeekEarning != totalYearEarning) ){
        alert("currentWeekEarning  Not Equal to totalYearEarning");
        return false;

      }
      if ( currentLoss != totalYearLoss) {
        alert(' currentLoss Not Equal to totalYearLoss');
        return false;
      }
    }


    DoSave = (function(fn){
      return function(){
      var resultofalertMSGS = alertMSGS();
      if (resultofalertMSGS === false) {
       // so if the function returns  false then  i need to exit from the (DoSave Function) and if it satisfies then i need to perform the (DoSave Function)
      }
        var result=fn.apply(fn, arguments);
        return result;
      }
    })(DoSave);
```

Comment: Sorry but, why do you try to do something so complicated? Can't you write your `DoSave` function outside `alertMSGS` function and call it in?

Comment: yeah i agree with fefux

Answer (score 0):

it is Just an idea how you can achieve it. Try.

```
DoSave = (function(fn){

      var resultofalertMSGS = alertMSGS();
      if (resultofalertMSGS) {
      (DoSave); // do here what u want to do for saving data

      }

        var result=fn.apply(fn, arguments); // decide whether it should come inside if or else
        return result;
      }
    })
```

Comment: actually that was there in your code. i exactly dont know why and how you are using that function.

Comment: But it was working fine , when i tried in console.log i am getting the return as false. So the last think is just to exit the DoSave Function. can you suggest any alernative way

Comment: then return result after dosave function and place this fn.apply in proper place where u want to call

Answer (score 0):

Changed the code slightly , worked for me . Any ways thanks

```
   DoSave = (function(fn){
      return function(){
      var resultofalertMSGS = alertMSGS();
      if (resultofalertMSGS === false) {
          return false;      
      }else{
        var result=fn.apply(fn, arguments);
        return result;
      }
    }
    })(DoSave);
```